# Ajax POST not working $_POST

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm attempting to submit a contact form to a php file via ajax. I use phpMailer to send form results. The POST doesnt appear to be working however. When I submit, neither the success or error conditions execute. When I comment out the POST variables, the ajax request executes successfully and the email sends (variables blank). Here is the code...

```
<form  method="post" class="form2" id="form2Id" name="form" action="">

            <div class="formtitle">Form<</div>

            <div class="input">
                <div class="inputtext">Your Name: </div>
                <div class="inputcontent">

                    <input id="nameId" type="text" name="name" />

                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="input">
                <div class="inputtext">Your Phone Number: </div>
                <div class="inputcontent">

                    <input id="phoneNumberId" type="text" name="phoneNumber" />

                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="input">
                <div class="inputtext">Your Email Address: </div>
                <div class="inputcontent">

                    <input id="emailAddressId" type="text" name="emailAddress"/>

                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="inputtextbox nobottomborder">
                <!--<div class="inputtext">Message: </div>-->
                <div class="inputcontent">

                    <!--<textarea id="messageId" class="textarea" name="message"></textarea>-->

                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="buttons">

                <input class="orangebutton" type="submit" id="formSubmit" value="Submit" />

            </div>

        </form>
```

```
$( "#formSubmit" ).click(function() {
$("#form2Id").validate({
debug: true,
 submitHandler: function(form) {

$.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: "handler.php",
 data: $(form).serialize(),
 timeout: 12000,
 success: function() { alert("Success"); },
  error: function() { alert("FAILURE"); }
 });
return false;
}
});
});

)};
```

```
<?php

require("./PHPMailer-master/class.phpmailer.php");
include("./PHPMailer-master/class.smtp.php"); // optional, gets called from within class.phpmailer.php if not already loaded

//collect the posted variables into local variables before calling $mail = new mailer

$nameId = $_POST['nameId'];
$phoneNumberId = $_POST['phoneNumberId'];
$emailAddressId = $_POST['emailAddressId'];

$mail = new PHPMailer();

//$body = file_get_contents('contents.html');
//$body = eregi_replace("[]",'',$body);

$mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
$mail->Host = "lll"; // SMTP server
//$mail->SMTPDebug = 1; // enables SMTP debug information (for testing)
// 1 = errors and messages
// 2 = messages only
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // enable SMTP authentication
$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl"; // sets the prefix to the servier
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com"; // sets GMAIL as the SMTP server
$mail->Port = 465; // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
$mail->Username = "lll@gmail.com"; // GMAIL username
$mail->Password = "..."; // GMAIL password

$mail->SetFrom('lll@gmail.com', 'UUU');

$mail->AddReplyTo("lll@gmail.com","UUU");

$mail->Subject = "Email subject";
optional, comment out and test
$mail->MsgHTML($body);


$address = $emailAddressId;
$mail->AddAddress($address, "MMM");



$mail->Body="
 Name: $nameId
 Phone: $phoneNumberId
 Email: $emailAddressId
";

if(!$mail->Send()) {
echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
echo "
 <h2>Thank you. We will contact you shortly.</h2>
 ";
}
 ?>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: try print_r($_POST); in php and see what are the variable get postin to page  and then parse your need  values from it ,as use serilaze data in ajax data option

Comment: So somewhere in the process of hooking into a form, submitting it through ajax, processing it in PHP, sending a response and e-mailing its contents, something goes wrong? Please narrow down your question. Strip it down to a minimal piece of code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: please try to narrow down your question http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: If I comment out the post vars,

Answer (score 2):

Given html line `<input id="nameId" type="text" name="name" />` and this php code `$nameId = $_POST['nameId'];` you will indeed end up with an empty `$nameId`, because the posted value is in `$_POST['name']`. The same goes for your other variables.

Answer (score 0):

If I comment out the post vars,

```
$nameId = $_POST['name'];
$phoneNumberId = $_POST['phoneNumber'];
$emailAddressId = $_POST['emailAddress'];
```

the email sends successfully as long as I type in a valid email address. Otherwise, the email does not send at all. In both instances, ajax returns a successful response. I've tried the above suggestion of using the names instead of the ids, but it sill does not work.